# Uncaught TypeError: form.steps is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am trying to make a simple wizard for my form. But it will give me "CursusWizard.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: form.steps is not a function" error.

I am also working with Angular for the first time and I think maybe it has something to do with my javascript not working properly.

Here is my html with form:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Cursus </title>
  </head>

 <form id="example-advanced-form" class="form-horizontal" name="form" action="#" ng-submit="addCursus()">
 <h3>Cursus aanmaken</h3>
    <fieldset>
    <legend> Cursus informatie</legend>

  <label for ="naam"> Cursus naam</label>
    <input id="naam" name="naam" type="text" class="required" ng-model="formCursus.name">


    <label for ="cursuscode"> Cursus code</label>
    <input id="cursuscode" name="cursuscode" type="text" class="required" ng-model="formCursus.cursuscode">


    <label for ="aantalec">Aantal ec </label>
    <input name="aantalec" type="text" list="aantalec" class="required" ng-model="formCursus.aantalec">
    <datalist id="aantalec">
        <option value="Boston">
        <option value="Cambridge">
    </datalist>

    <label for ="periode">Periode </label>
    <input name="periode" type="text" list="periode" class="required" ng-model="formCursus.periode">
    <datalist id="periode">
        <option value="Boston">
        <option value="Cambridge">
    </datalist>

<button class="btn-default" type="submit">Add</button>

    <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
</fieldset>


<h3>Profile</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Profile Information</legend>

    <label for="name-2">First name *</label>
    <input id="name-2" name="name" type="text" class="required">
    <label for="surname-2">Last name *</label>
    <input id="surname-2" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
    <label for="email-2">Email *</label>
    <input id="email-2" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
    <label for="address-2">Address</label>
    <input id="address-2" name="address" type="text">
    <label for="age-2">Age (The warning step will show up if age is less than 18) *</label>
    <input id="age-2" name="age" type="text" class="required number">
    <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
</fieldset>

<h3>Warning</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>You are to young</legend>

    <p>Please go away ;-)</p>
</fieldset>

<h3>Finish</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>

    <input id="acceptTerms-2" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms-2">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
</fieldset>

</form>
  </html>
```

Here is my code with javascript:

```
    var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();

    form.steps({
headerTag: "h3",
bodyTag: "fieldset",
transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
{
    // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
    if (currentIndex > newIndex)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young
    if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
    if (currentIndex < newIndex)
    {
        // To remove error styles
        form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
        form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
    }
    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
    return form.valid();
},
onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
{
    // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
    if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18)
    {
        form.steps("next");
    }
    // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
    if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
    {
        form.steps("previous");
    }
},
onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
{
    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
    return form.valid();
},
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
{
    alert("Submitted!");
}
 }).validate({
errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
rules: {
    confirm: {
        equalTo: "#password-2"
    }
}
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();
```

you are assigning the value returned by `.show()` to the variable `form`, as per my knowledge, in jquery .show() does not return any value, so probably the form would not have a method method `step()` and the reference form.step() will lead to an error.

Answer (score 0):

have you included the jquery cdn for steps function?
please refer the below cdn link, try executing by adding cdn and post your finding once added.
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js"

happy coding!